# SML - Base case, wrong return value for declared datatype

Tags: pattern-matching, sml, smlnj, type-mismatch

I'm having trouble with the base case of a function that I'm writing.  I have a datatype that I've declared.  In the base case I need to replace the nil with something.  How do I tell it that the function won't return anything?

```
datatype 'a newThing = Cons of 'a option * (unit -> 'a newThing);

fun permutation [] = Cons(NONE, fn () => nil)
|   permutation l = .....;


Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: 'Z option * (unit -> 'Z newThing)
operand:         'Z option * (unit -> 'Y list)
in expression:
Cons (NONE,(fn () => nil))
```

EDIT: I'm not allowed to change the datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your datatype only has the `Cons` value constructor (indicating another element), but you want a `Nil` constructor (indicating no further elements).

The typechecker then gives you a type error, because you attempt to return a `nil`, which is of the `'a list` type, rather than `'a newThing`.

What you want to do is add a `Nil` constructor to your `'a newThing` datatype, and return this value in the base case.

```
datatype 'a newThing = Cons of 'a option * (unit -> 'a newThing)
                     | Nil

fun permutation [] = Nil
  | permutation l = ...
```

If you are to not change your datatype, there is no way to terminate the list. It will always keep going, as the only thing you can have is a `Cons`, which represents another element.

Assuming there are no `NONE` elements in the lists you want to represent, you could let the value of `NONE` signify the end of the list, and simply keep returning `NONE` infinitely once you run out of elements.

```
fun permutation [] = Cons(NONE, permutation [])
```

You could also throw an exception, if you wish:

```
exception EndOfNewThing

fun permutation [] = raise EndOfNewThing
```

Honestly, though, these are pretty poor solutions compared to adding a new value constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I didn't tell you that I'm not allowed to change the datatype.  I'll add that into the question post.

Comment: Also I didn't know you could do that so at least I learned from your post!

Comment: I added in raising an exception which gets the job done, thank you!